# nonce attribute in "script" tag incorrectly parsed

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, content-security-policy

Here is the problem:

Within an iframed web app, a javascript source is inserted using "script" tag, with "nonce" attribute to bypass CSP. Somehow the "nonce" tag is incorrectly parsed, e.g.:

```
<script src="//www.example.com/asdf.js" nonce="isaghdfuigisdfu"></script>
```

will send an XHR to this wrong url:

```
https://www.example.com/asdf.js%22%20nonce=%22isaghdfuigisdfu
```

which means the spaces, quote, and "nonce" becomes part of the src url.

Is it because iframed app doesn't support the nonce attr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's because wrong parsing by your script the source for XHR request: `https://www.example.com/asdf.js%22%20nonce=%22isaghdfuigisdfu` -> `https://www.example.com/asdf.js" nonce="isaghdfuigisdfu`.

The 'nonce' attr is definitely supported in `<script>`. If browser does not support some attribute, it will just skip it.